# Multiselect price filter attribute in layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.8, layered-navigation

I want to implement Price filter with multi select in layered navigation. It is looking like this.
Price:

1. 0 - 5000
2. 5000 - 10000
3. 10000 - 15000
4. 15000 - above

I have succeeded with other multi select filter attributes. 
Can you please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you really want it hard coded, that way, just hardcode it that way?

Answer (score 1):

changing the price attribute might be a big undertaking. You could make a second price attribute, calling it `price_filter` for example that is multi select and has these steps set.
You will need to set both the normal price and the value of the `price_filter` attribute but the result on the front-end will be what you're looking for.